# How can I modify Angular navigation like http request with HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**My goal:**

I would like to navigation with

```js
route.navigation(['path', 'to'])
```

and

```html
<a [routerLink]="['path', 'to']">
```

I use `global filter` what I store in `NgRx` and put into URL queries all time in order to when I send link to another user who opens site and activate automatically filter setting from URL queries.

> Like: "/path/to?timeframe=1576652167_1576662167".

**My Question:**

How can I solve that if I navigate with `<a routerLink>` or `navigate()` method and this navigation path redefine with `any handler` the URL query for all navigation without redirect?

Of course: I don't want to use `[queryParams]` because it has to write all the time and pass query data.

See as: `HttpInterceptor`. Here we can modify HTTP request. For example `headers`. Is there similar to navigation?

Answer (score 0):

My first try soution:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'foo',
        // ...
    },
    {
        path: 'bar',
        // ...
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FilterService {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    /**
     * @description
     * To With Filter
     *
     * @param commands any[]
     * @param extras NavigationExtras
     */
   twf(
        commands: any[],
        extras: NavigationExtras = {}
    ): string {
        let filter = '';

        Object.keys(this.global).forEach(key => {
            filter += filter === '' ? (key + '=' + this.global[key]) : ('&' + key + '=' + this.global[key]);
        });

        return '#' + this.router.createUrlTree(commands, extras).toString() + '?' + filter;
    }
}
```

```js
export class FooComponent {
    constructor(private filter: FilterService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        // output: { xxx: "aaa", yyy: "10" }
        console.log(route.snapshot.queryParams);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- http://localhost:4200/#/foo?xxx=aaa&yyy=10 -->
<a [href]="filter.twf(['/foo'])">...</a>

<!-- http://localhost:4200/#/bar?xxx=aaa&yyy=10 -->
<a [href]="filter.twf(['/bar'])">...</a>
```